# Is an "Apply" method required to save programmatical changes to the QGIS project file?

Tags: qgis, python

I'm trying to change the nodata settings on a large number of color index raster layers in my project. I want to swap the original nodata with one specified by the user.

The Python code I've written works kind of like it should. The Nodata I specify is applied in the map, but the original Nodata value also remains (leaving me with two Nodata values.)

The change is also reflected in the "Layer properties -> Transparency" window. However, when I save the project and re-open it, the changes made by the script are lost. If I manually do the nodata changes in the GUI, they are saved to the project file as they should.

Am I missing some sort of "Apply" method in my script? Or have I misunderstood that dataProvider() is the correct class to do this?

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

#Display user prompt for nodata
qid = QInputDialog()
title = "Enter nodata value"
label = "Nodata value: "
mode = QLineEdit.Normal
default = ""

#Get input from user
nodata, ok = QInputDialog.getText(qid, title, label, mode, default)
#Cast user nodata value to int
nodata = int(nodata)

li = iface.legendInterface()
#Get all visible layers
visiblelayers = [layer for layer in li.layers() if li.isLayerVisible(layer)]

#Iterate over all visible layers
for layer in visiblelayers:

  #Get data provider
  provider = layer.dataProvider()

  #Do not use source nodata value
  provider.setUseSrcNoDataValue(1,False)
  #Use nodata value from user 
  provider.setNoDataValue(1,nodata)

  print "Nodata set to",nodata,"on",layer.name()
  layer.setCacheImage(None)
  layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: It seems so. Using a layer from a Postgis db changes can be saved using `layer.startEditing()` then your code (containing something like `layer.addFeature(thefeaturetoadd)` or `layer.updateFeature(theupdatedfeature)` and finally commit the changes with `layer.commitChanges()`. That worked for me at least.